# Void in single expression arrow functions

Tags: javascript

I'm looking into the use cases for the good old `void` operator. One that I've seen mentioned is for preventing arrow functions from "leaking" their result, because of the way they're often written (see `fn0` in example below).

So the argument is to use `void` to prevent such leaks in the cases you don't actually need the result (see `fn2`) but I don't really see what the difference is with just wrapping the statement in brackets (see `fn1`).

```js
function doSomething(number) { return number + 1 }

const fn0 = () => doSomething(1)
const fn1 = () => { doSomething(1) }
const fn2 = () => void doSomething(1)

console.log(fn0()) // 2
console.log(fn1()) // undefined
console.log(fn2()) // undefined
```

Could someone explain to me what the differences are between `fn1` and `fn2`? Does it do something different "under the hood"? Is it just a matter of convention / readability?

Comment: I *guess* using `void` is more explicit so nobody (another developer, Future You, etc.) mistakenly thinks you just forgot a `return` statement?

Comment: *"...but I don't really see what the difference is with just wrapping the statement in brackets..."* There isn't any, both achieve the same result. Using `void` is just longer and more obscure. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...but I don't really see what the difference is with just wrapping the statement in brackets...

There isn't any significant difference, both achieve the same result. Using `void` is just more characters and more obscure. :-)

> Could someone explain to me what the differences are between `fn1` and `fn2`? Does it do something different "under the hood"?

Not really. It takes a different path to the same destination, but in both cases the result of calling the functions is `undefined`. As you know, `fn1` gets there by using a full function body (the `{}`), and `fn2` gets there by applying the `void` operator, but there's no subtle difference lurking in there.

Comment: Thank you for addressing my entire question, including that there's "no subtle difference lurking in there"

Comment: (Though, I disagree that `void` is more obscure. I think it makes it actually more clear what the intent of the code is.)

Comment: @Sheraff - Fair enough. **:-)** My point is that the `void` operator, itself, is obscure. Most JavaScript programmers have no idea what it does, so on seeing `fn2` they won't know what `fn2` does. (Hopefully they go look it up at that point, which is more easily done with `void` than with some other operators...)

Answer (score 4):

All that `void` does is:

> The void operator evaluates the given expression and then returns undefined.

So, it's the same as returning `undefined`.

When you don't explicitly `return` anything from a function, `undefined` is returned by default. So there's no difference here.

Other equivalents:

```js
function doSomething(number) { return number + 1 }

const fn1 = () => { doSomething(1) }
const fn2 = () => void doSomething(1)
const fn3 = () => {
  doSomething(1);
  return undefined;
}
function fn4() {
  doSomething(1);
}
function fn5() {
  return void doSomething(1);
}
function fn6() {
  doSomething(1);
  return void 'foo';
}

console.log(fn1()) // undefined
console.log(fn2()) // undefined
console.log(fn3()) // undefined
console.log(fn4()) // undefined
console.log(fn5()) // undefined
console.log(fn6()) // undefined
```

(note that the use of an arrow function vs a non-arrow function doesn't make a difference, except for the fact that arrow functions can lack `{`s, in which case they implicitly return the following expression, which may be `undefined` or not)

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted, but I understand it: this answer seems to be geared towards explaining "javascript 101". Whereas my question was about "are there subtleties beyond the obviously similar behavior".

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to change the view on `void`, because this can clearly show in the code, to throw away a return value from a function by using a call and omit the result of it.

For example, if you have

```
void someFunction();
```

you describe a pattern, which returns something and this result is not used in the code.

If you have just this

```
someFunction();
```

and the function returns something useful, the review of the code may mention the unused result of it.